Limit of a piecewise function using $\epsilon$-$\delta_\epsilon$ definition
I have the following problem:
$$\text{Let the heavisise function be defined as }H(x) = \begin{cases} 0, & x\lt0\\1, & \geq0 \end{cases}\\ \text{Prove that the function }H(x) \text{ is not continuous}$$
The module that this problem came from has only covered the ${\epsilon}-{\delta}_{\epsilon}$ method of continuity, which i could not figure out how to do for this function. I then tried using the fact that if $\lim_{x{\to}a+}(H(x))\;{\neq}\;\lim_{x{\to}a-}(H(x))$ for some $a{\in}{\mathbb{R}}$, then the function is not continous at that point, so the overall function is not continuous.
$$\lim_{x{\to}0+}(H(x))=1,\;\lim_{x{\to}0-}(H(x))=0\;{\Rightarrow}\text{H(x) is not continous at x =0 }$$
However proving these limits to be true is stumping me. For example, looking at the left hand limit:
$$\text{if }\lim_{x{\to}0+}(H(x))=1,\text{then }{\forall}{\epsilon}\gt0,{\exists}{\delta}_{\epsilon}\gt0\;{\forall}x\in{\mathbb{R}}:|x-0|\lt{\delta}_{\epsilon}\;{\Rightarrow}|H(X)-H(0)|\lt{\epsilon}\\$$
$$\text{consider }|H(x)-H(0)|\lt{\epsilon}{\iff}|H(x)-1|\lt{\epsilon}$$
Here, there is no way to define H(x) in terms of x for all $x\in{\mathbb{R}}$, so i am stuck on what to do here. If anyone knows how to either prove this limit, or prove the discontinuity of H(x) using the ${\epsilon}-{\delta}_{\epsilon}$ continuity definition then any help would be appreciated. thanks!

You are working too hard. To show that the function is not continuous at $x=0$ just think about why there can be no $\delta$ for some well chosen small value of $\epsilon$.

Take $x=- \delta_{\epsilon} /2$ with $0 <\epsilon <1$ to get a  contradiction.

The approach is sensible, and what I would do in the same circumstance: show the one-sided limits exist, but are not equal to each other. However, you don't seem to have the correct definitions to hand. What you have written down is the (two-sided) definition of continuity. For the limit from the right, to show it is equal to some number $L$, we show:
$$\forall \varepsilon > 0, \exists \delta_\varepsilon > 0 : \forall x \in \Bbb{R}, 0 < x - 0 < \delta_\varepsilon \implies |H(x) - L| < \varepsilon.$$
Note: there are two differences here. For one, the limit is now a more general $L$, not $H(0)$. Based on your (sound) intuition, we expect $L = 1$ to work. The other difference is the lack of absolute values around $x - 0$. This is what makes it a limit from the right; we insist both that $x$ be to the right of $0$ (hence the $0 < x - 0$), but also nearby (hence the $x - 0 < \delta_\varepsilon$). If we wanted the limit from the left, we would have $-\delta_\varepsilon < x - 0 < 0$.
So, with the correct definition, we should be able to proceed, but it doesn't solve the core issue you're having: you don't seem to know how to metabolise the $H(x)$ term. By the definition of $H(x)$, we know that $H(x) = 1$ for any $x \ge 0$. So, regardless of what we set $\delta_\varepsilon$ to be, we know that for any $x$ satisfying $0 < x - 0 < \delta_\varepsilon$, we'll have $H(x) = 1$, and so
$$0 < x - 0 < \delta_\varepsilon \implies |H(x) - 1| = |1 - 1| = 0 < \varepsilon,$$
for any $\varepsilon > 0$. What this tells me is that the value of $\delta_\varepsilon$ does not need to depend on $\varepsilon$. The above works or any value $\varepsilon > 0$ thrown at us, and regardless of the value of $\delta_\varepsilon$. We could set $\delta_\varepsilon = 147$, for every given $\varepsilon$, and the definition would be satisfied. This is a unique property of constant functions, or at least, functions constant to the right of $0$.
Try doing the same for the left hand limit. Show that it is $0$, bearing in mind that $H(x) = 0$ for $x < 0$. Once you establish the limits exist, but are different, you're done.

Alternative approach:
To provide an $~\epsilon,~\delta~$ oriented proof that a function is not continuous, an alternative approach is to dispense with any consideration of left side limit versus right side limit.
Instead, you can look at the specific definition of continuity, and prove that the constraint can not be satisfied.
Personally, first, I would take the intuitive approach, then I would use that approach to construct a formal analytical argument.

$\underline{\text{The Intuitive Approach}}$
Continuity over a domain implies continuity at each element in the domain.  Here, it is clear that the domain element in alleged violation is $~x = 0.~$
So, the demonstration may be limited to showing that the function is not continuous as $~x = 0.$
Informally, the continuity definition requires that for any $~\epsilon > 0,~$ you can construct a $~\delta$-neighborhood around $~x = 0,~$ such that for each element $~x_1~$ that is both in the function's domain and in this
$~\delta$-neighborhood, that $~H(x_1)~$ is in the $~\epsilon$-neighborhood around $~H(0).~$
So, looking at the function's specification, suppose, just for illustrative purposes, that $~\epsilon = 1/4,~$ and $~\delta = \dfrac{1}{1000000}.$
Then, I can find at least one element $~x_1~$ such that

$~x_1~$ is in the domain.

$~x_1~$ is in the $~\delta$-neighborhood.

$~H(x_1)~$ is not in the $~\epsilon$-neighborhood.


That is, $~x_1 = \dfrac{-1}{2000000}~$ satisfies the above bullet points.
However, to violate the continuity definition, I would have to show that for the specific value $~\epsilon = 1/4,~$ that it is impossible to find any satisfying $~\delta.$
So far, all I have done is show that $~\delta = \dfrac{1}{1000000}~$ is unsatisfactory.
Then, when looking more deeply at the specification, I realize that any negative $~x_1,~$ no matter how small in absolute value, will cause the necessary violation.
So, for any $~\delta > 0,~$ I can set $~x_1 = \dfrac{-\delta}{2},~$ and trigger the violation.
This implies that no such satisfying $~\delta~$ exists, for the value $~\epsilon = 1/4.~$
Consequently, in this section, a successful demonstration has in fact been informally constructed.
Therefore, the problem reduces to converting the informal (intuitive) analysis in this section into formal analysis.

$\underline{\text{The Formal Approach}}$
Let $~D~$ denote the domain of $~H(x).$
To show that the function $~H(x)~$ is not continuous throughout $~D,~$ it is sufficient to show that the function is not continuous at $~x = 0.~$
To show that the function $~H(x)~$ is not continuous at $~x = 0,~$ it is sufficient to show that for the specific value $~\epsilon = 1/4,~$ it is impossible to find any $~\delta > 0,~$ such that
$$\left\{ ~~0 < | ~x_1 - 0 ~| < \delta ~~\text{and} ~~x_1 \in D ~~\right\}$$
implies
$$| ~H(x_1) - H(0) ~| < 1/4.$$
The demonstration will be by contradiction.
Suppose that such a $~\delta > 0~$ existed.
Consider the element $~x_1 = \dfrac{-\delta}{2}.$
Then:

$0 < | ~x_1 - 0 ~| < \delta.$

$~x_1 \in D.$

$~H(x_1) = 0, ~H(0) = 1 \implies $
$| ~H(x_1) - H(0) > 1/4.$


This contradicts the assertion that some satisfying $~\delta~$ exists.
Therefore, for the specific value $~\epsilon = 1/4,~$ no satisfying $~\delta~$ exists.
Therefore, the specification for continuity at $~x = 0~$ has been violated.
Therefore $~H(x)~$ is not continuous at $~x = 0.$
